# Can anyone give examples of difference between domain name, host name and server name?

Tags: dns, hosting

I want to learn more about the certificates. How to create them and how do they work. In that context can anyone explain me the difference between names. I am entirely new to this field to bear my question.

Comment: Do you already know how a DNS works? Do you know the difference between a domain and an IP address?

Comment: Yes I have a decent knowledge of these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Domain name" is a term used in the DNS system.

"Host name" is a term used in the context of server instances.

"Server name" is a term that's used generally without being will defined at all.

All three terms are often used in contexts where they are strictly speaking wrong. For example, you can easily find hundreds of examples here on Stack Overflow where web programmers write "domain name" when they mean "URL".

The same string can (and often is) used in all different contexts. This can very easily lead to confusion, so it's important to be clear what one means in each instance.